# how to compare the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This my code

I am getting email address from database through ajax and mysql it is giving me value in . so in below FUNCTION comparing() i am retriving data from span to compare with the textfield data. but it is not comparing properly.
Please help me out

```
function validate(pageForm) 
    {
    /************Getting error values in return values***********************/
    var returncomparing = "";

    /*********************************/
      //FIELD WHICH YOU HAVE TO VALDATE

      returncomparing += comparing(pageForm.email);
     /********************************************/


      if (returncomparing != "") 
      {

          document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = returnIndustry;

      }

          return false;
    }
```

After giving correct EMAIL still it is giving Error ... (Please Provide Login User ID)

```
function comparing(pageForm){
    var error = "";
     // var fetchedEmail=document.forms["pageForm"]["email_fetch"].value;
     var em=document.forms["pageForm"]["email"].value;
     //var emai = document.getElementById('emlTst').value;
     var email = document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML;
     //document.getElementById('emlTst').value = email;
    if(em != email){
        document.getElementById('error_email2').innerHTML="Please Provide Login User ID";
        pageForm.style.borderColor = 'red';
        error='5';
     }
     else  if(em == email){
            document.getElementById('error_email2').innerHTML="";
            error = "";
         }
         else {
             document.getElementById('error_email2').innerHTML="";
             pageForm.style.borderColor = '#c7c7c7';
             }
  return error;
}
/*************************************************************/
```

Comment: Why do you use the innerHtml property of the txtHint element? Isn't there a value property. This might be the problem if txtHint is not just a div or a span with text in it.

Comment: are you considering the case (upper/lower) of both the values? i'll suggest to convert both of the values to either to lower or upper before comparing their values.

Comment: definitely need `value` of form fields not `innerHTML` . Learn to use browser console to test your code

Comment: i use innerHTML to get the value from span tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var em = $('#email').val().toLowerCase();
 var email = $('#txtHint').val().toLowerCase();
```

Comment: @RexRoNy If you can ensure that's always the case then you don't need to do call `toLowerCase()`.